# Movie with car chase in Europe (1990s)

Tags: identify-this-movie

There's a movie that I saw a couple weeks ago, and wanted to revisit sometime but now I can't think of the title. It's an English movie from the mid-to-late 1990s where a man and a woman are followed by gunmen in a car.

They are chased through Europe and finally end up crashing the car near what looked to be a restaurant with a fountain. They then use their battered car to ram the one that was following them, which ruptures the gas tank and causes their car to explode, and they barely escape before it does. (The woman is concerned with legal documents in a case on the dash and so her escape is delayed, causing the man to have to practically drag her out.)

The actors are fairly high-profile (I had seen the man before, I keep thinking DeNiro or Cruise, but I know that's not right). The woman was a redhead and I think they were driving a BMW or Mercedes (the car was European).

I do know for a fact that it wasn't Ronin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Peacemaker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119874/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Here is the scene you are describing:

George Clooney and Nicole Kidman are the two high profile actors.

Comment: _The Peacemaker_ is almost forgotten now, and largely with good reason, but it has the minor distinction of being the first movie released by Dreamworks SKG.  A number of critics made the observation that Steven Spielberg, Jeffrey Katzenberg, and David Geffen put their heads together and couldn't come up with anything better than _this_?